# Capped reputation

Tags: support, reputation, daily-reputation-limit

I just read about the reputation cap of 200, and I have two questions.

1. Say that it happens I get more than twenty upvotes for my answers in one day. Will the reputation beyond capped be permanently lost, or will it be added back later?
2. Is there anyplace where I can check how much below the cap I am today?

Comment: In addition, suppose you hit the 200 cap, and then do something to lose reputation. Will it go down to 198, or will the runoff cover for it?

Comment: @JoeZ. It will go down to $198$, but the cap is lifted as well (that is, you can earn $2$ more reputation).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

1. It will not be counted unless the rule is changed.
2. Just check the Recent Activity page (click the envelope on the top), and click "Today". See [*How do I know if I’ve reached my daily rep cap?*](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/40714/how-do-i-know-if-ive-reached-my-daily-rep-cap) on meta.SO for detail.